# How to fill in new column with values calculated from the same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that I am looking to alter by adding a new column (Total Price). I then want to populate this new column (Total Price) with values calculated from two other columns (Quantity and Unit Cost). Below is my SQL I have which has created a new column in my table but I can not figure out how to populate the new column (Total Price). I've tried SET and AS with no luck. Sorry I am new to SQL and appreciate the help!!!

The table I am altering is "purchase order details" and all the data I need is in this table to populate the new column (Total Price) by multiplying quantity and unit cost.

```
ALTER TABLE [purchase order details]
ADD COLUMN [total price] currency

SET [purchase order details].[total price] = [purchase order 
details].quantity * [purchase order details].[unit cost]

FROM [purchase order details]
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLI

ALTER TABLE purchase_order_details
ADD COLUMN total_price;

UPDATE
SET purchase_order_details = quantity*unit_cost;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new column first using ALTER TABLE command and then populate it using the UPDATE command. These two commands are separate and cannot be combined.

```
ALTER TABLE [purchase order details]
ADD COLUMN [total price] currency;

UPDATE [purchase order details]
SET [purchase order details].[total price] =
    [purchase order details].quantity * [purchase order details].[unit cost];
```

Comment: Hi Racil, I did that and still got and error "Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement. Makes not sense to me since the new column was already added to the table.

Comment: Did you run the two commands separately as I said? Anyway, if the column is added successfully, then we probably don't need to worry about that. Just run the `UPDATE` command alone now.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know what you meant to do the two commands separate. I thought the ; separates two commands. I put the commands into two query's and it worked. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [purchase order details]
ADD COLUMN [total price] currency;

EXEC('
    SET [purchase order details].[total price] = [purchase order 
    details].quantity * [purchase order details].[unit cost]
    FROM [purchase order details]');
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Trigger function. Don't do anything in the MVC side.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Total_Price_Calculator ON [purchase order details] AFTER INSERT AS
UPDATE [purchase order details]
SET [purchase order details].[total price] =
    [purchase order details].quantity * [purchase order details].[unit cost];
```